# Eclipse Java Build Path Jar Library classes not found even if available in jar

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, buildpath, nebula

Recently I wanted to add the nebula shelf to my eclipse plugin. Therefore I added the org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.pshelf.source_1.1.0.201701302244.jar the build path of my eclipse project. 
Sadly eclipse can't find the class files inside of the jar, even after cleaning and rebuilding the whole project.

Picture: [image]

Checking the same jar file with jd-gui results in:

Picture: [image]

I exported the *.java files with jd-gui and copied them to my project. Using this method my project built successfully and worked as expected.

Can someone tell me how I can use the jar file without exporting all of the java files manually? Thanks for your help! :-)

Comment: Maybe there is a conflict with another class with same name ?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use source jars. You can tell `eclipse` while debugging to use the source jar.

Add the jar to build path: right click on jar -> `build path` -> `add to build path`

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to add Eclipse plugins directly to the build path of another plugin as it won't work.

Instead add the plugin to your target platform or import it in to your workspace.

Then add the plugin to your plugin's Dependencies. In the MANIFEST.MF editor you do this on the 'Dependencies' tab in the 'Required Plug-ins' list.